# I am getting an error when I try to build the production build using the ckeditor5 with angular app

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am using [ckedtior5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html)  in a component in my angular app.

It works without a problem locally but when I try to build prod its throwing this error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/fesm5/ckeditor-ckeditor5-angular.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js): TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

I cannot see any property named 'kind' in the file mentioned in the error

```
// Module

import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
imports: [
// other imports
CKEditorModule
]

// Component
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
public Editor = ClassicEditor;

// Html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 mt-4">
              <label>Info</label>
              <ckeditor [editor]="Editor"
               data="<p>Hello World</p>"></ckeditor>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what the problem is but I tried to use ngx-quill as a replacement and it throws the same error when I try to build --prod --aot.

Now I downgraded to a lower version of ngx-quill (6.3.1) and and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm using ckeditor4 and got this error when I build the project with *build --prod*

I solved it by adding *"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true* in tsconfig.js:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
```

and changing "buildOptimizer" to false in angular.json

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Reference: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78